# Exact double division

Tags: c++, rounding-error, floor-division

Consider the following function:

```
auto f(double a, double b) -> int
{
  return std::floor(a/b);
}
```

So I want to compute the largest integer `k` such that `k * b <= a` in a mathematical sense.
As there could be rounding errors, I am unsure whether the above function really computes this `k`. I do not worry about the case that `k` could be out of range.
What is the proper way to determine this `k` for sure?

Comment: The range of values for `double` is larger than for `int`, so some values are simply too large or too small for `int`. You're not handling that case in any way. That said, I've done similar things in the past and simply wrote unit tests for corner cases.

Comment: I would recommend finding k using your function, then checking if k-1, k and k+1 satisfy the condition. Then pick the largest which satisfies. (you may need to use long long)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how strict you are. Take a double b and an integer n, and calculate b*n. Then a will be rounded. If a is rounded down, then it is less than the mathematical value of n*b, and a/b is mathematically less than n. You will get a result if n instead of n-1.

On the other hand, a == b*n will be true. So the “correct” result could be surprising.

Your condition was that “k*b <= a”. If we interpret this as “the result of multiplying k*b using double precision is <= a”, then you’re fine. If we interpret it as “the mathematically exact product of k and b is <= a”, then you need to calculate k*b - a using the fma function and check the result. This will tell you the truth, but might return a result of 4 if a was calculated as 5.0 * b and was rounded down.

Comment: So you are saying that the function always produces the right result? Why can `n` not be the nearest floating point number?

Comment: Sorry, had to correct this. You get the “wrong” result when a == b*n due to rounding, but mathematically a/b < n. So k*b <= a due to rounding errors only.

Comment: When we divide, our number as we generate it is always less than the actual answer. Although the number printed by `double` might show rounding up, in the complete internal representation, we can always say that it is lesser than the rounded-up integer.

Comment: I saw rounding down only for n really high, it was fine for integer range.
```
    double n = pow(10,23);
    double b = 999999999999999;
    double a = n*b;
    printf("%.17lf %17lf\n",a,b);
    printf("%.17lf %lf\n",a/b,floor(a/b));
```
```
99999999999999884412014234584548900864.00000000000000000 999999999999999.000000
99999999999999991611392.00000000000000000 99999999999999991611392.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that float division is not exact.

`a/b` can give `1.9999` instead of `2`, and `std::floor` can then give `1`.

One simple solution is to add a small value prior calling `std::floor`:

```
std::floor (a/b + 1.0e-10);
```

Result:

```
result = 10 while 11 was expected
With eps added, result = 11
```

**Test code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main () {
    double b = atan (1.0);
    int x = 11;
    double a = x * b;
    int y = std::floor (a/b);
    std::cout << "result = " << y << " while " << x << " was expected\n";
    
    double eps = 1.0e-10;
    int z = std::floor (a/b + eps);
    std::cout << "With eps added, result = " << z << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that I have assumed here that the ratio is positive. to be checked/adapted if it is negative.

Comment: I doubt that such an approach can work because you result is changed if `a = b-eps`. Then the answer is `k=0`, bout you would get `k=1`.

Comment: No. If the mathematically exact result is 2, it cannot be rounded to 1.999999999. Rounding can never round “past” a floating point number, so the result is _never_ too small.

Comment: In practice, I have used this approach for decades. One issue is that you have rounding errors on calculations of `a` and `b`, and rounding errors when calculating `a/b`. There is no way to make a posteriori distinction between them. You can find corner cases when this approach will fail effectively, However, in these situations, it is likely that the only way to solve them is to use a number representation with a higher number of bits.

Comment: @gnasher729 2 cannot be rounded directly to 1.999999. But a calculation that is theoritically supposed to give 2 can give 1.999999. My wording can be unprecise. Looks at the code example.